# Where do I specify to Postgres within Docker that it should run and accept connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize an existing Rails app that uses Postgresql 9.5 as its database. In my docker-compose.yml. After a successful "docker-compose build" I can run the "docker-compose up" command and see the connection but when I navigate to localhost I get the following error.

> PG::ConnectionBad
>   could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running >locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket >"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Here is what is in my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
    environment:
       POSTGRES_USER: username
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
       POSTGRES_DB: hardware_development

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

From what I've seen I need to do some specification somewhere in my dockerfile or the docker-compose.yml but I either don't see a change or end up back at the same error.

I've been able to use Docker's own docs to use Docker Compose to create a new rails app with postgres where I see the "yay you're on rails!" page but now with my own code I can't see anything. Running the app outside of docker shows me the test page as well so its not the code within my rails app or the Postgres evnironment outside of Docker.

Comment: When the error message asks "is the server running locally", it's not.  In this setup it should be reachable on the hostname `db`.

Comment: Where do I put the hostname? In the docker-compose.yml or somewhere else?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database is probably an okay starting point; but it's just like any other Rails application where the database isn't running locally.

Comment: Yeah, I got there on my own and specified "db" as the host in my config/database.yml file but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `db` docker-compose entry isn't exposing any ports.  It needs to expose 5432.  Add a ports line for that just like you have for `web`.

Edit: also I don't know why you added `restart: always` to your database container, but I wouldn't recommend that for rails or pretty much anything.